# Change color of child element if specific condition is satisfies

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to change the color of a child element if it has "out of stock message". The Message will be generated at run time, so it can be changed for other items and I want to change the color only if the text is "out of stock". I can not modify the code I only can apply css or javascript / jquery.
Here is my html code:

```
<span id="stockStatus" class="status">
     <span id="itemavail">Out Of Stock</span>
</span>
```

I have tried this jQuery code but its not working:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".status").each(function(){
        if ($(this).children('span').text().trim() == "Out Of Stock") {
            $(this).children('span').css("color", "red");
        }
     });
});
```

Comment: You need to use `onchange` event

Comment: @user1881845: how are the new contents getting added?

Comment: <%=getCurrentAttribute('item','outofstockbehavior')%> this tag is modifiying the text..if item has out of stock text its color i need to change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after changing the content(you have not mentioned that how they are getting added on page), You can simply use:

```
$(".status span:contains(Out Of Stock)").css("color", "red");
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jv537fm6/)**

Comment: Message will change on runtime so I think he will need on change

Comment: Well not sure how is he modifying the dom.

Comment: I meant message will be different for other items

Comment: @Mr.Alien This is attached to the document.ready Function so i do not believe that is an issue. This solution will work for all colors or messages, just add a new line for each different message.

Comment: @user1881845 remove the `trim` - then it is working.

Comment: Yes its working fine in fiddle but in my website where multiple items has same class i dont know why its not working there

Comment: [site link](http://shopping.sandbox.netsuite.com/s.nl/c.3713628_SB2/n.2/it.A/id.2665/.f)

Comment: working fine when i am executing above code in console.

Comment: yes thanks its working fine but problem is that when im loading the page first it shows green color then it changes to red...how to fix it

Comment: you can hide the element in beginning and then show it after running above code.